# Exception at calling one program from another program inside Runnable interface

Tags: java

I am facing problem while I am trying to call another program from Task3 program and try to execute it on scheduled time. Getting exception at line 14 as below.

Please let me know where I am going wrong in call program from run method of Runnable interface.

> Task3.java:14: error: unreported exception Exception; must be caught or declar
>       to be thrown
>      Mult.main(new String[0]);

```java
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;

public class Task3 {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    TimerTask task = new TimerTask() {
      @Override
      public void run() {
        // task to run goes here
        System.out.println("Hello !!!");
        Mult.main(new String[0]);
      }
    };

    Timer timer = new Timer();
    long delay = 0;
    long intevalPeriod = 1 * 1000; 

    // schedules the task to be run in an interval 
    timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(task, delay,
                                intevalPeriod);

  } // end of main
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`Mult.main` has a `throws` clause that includes a checked exception, so for the code to be accepted by the compiler you'd need to add that exception to the `throws` clause of the `run` method or catch the exception.  You can't add that exception to the `throws` clause however, since you override [`TimerTask.run`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/TimerTask.html#run--), which declares no exceptions.

The only remaining opitions are catching that error or change `Mult.main` to not throw any exceptions that are not subclasses of [`RuntimeException`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/RuntimeException.html). You could e.g. catch the exception and throw a runtime exception or do something else, if an exception occurs:

```
TimerTask task = new TimerTask() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        // task to run goes here
        System.out.println("Hello !!!");
        try {
            Mult.main(new String[0]);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            // handle the exception,
            // in this case by throwing a RuntimeException with ex as cause
            throw new IllegalStateException("I didn't expect a exception.", ex);
        }
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a compile-time error. Your method `Mult.main()` can throw an `Exception`.

Surround it with try/catch to handle error, e.g.

```
try {
    Mult.main(new String[0]);
} catch (Exception e) {
    // Handle your error here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell without more code, but it looks like:

Mult.main(...) is defined as throwing an exception, in which case the code that calls must handle the exception.

Either:

1. Wrap the call to Mult.main(...) in a try-catch block, or
2. Define Task3.main(...) to throw Exception as well

P.S. or maybe it's timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(...), can't really tell without line numbers

Comment: it works..this basic concept to be taken care of..thanks you very much.... but addding  throw Exception  on main method doesnt worked as it expects ; after main method error throw declaration